# Ability to pick a primary tag of a question

Tags: feature-request, tags, title

Referenced question: [How to check if symlink can be created on a path?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/317881/how-to-check-if-symlink-can-be-created-on-a-path)

It has tags: `symlink`, `vagrant`, 'virtualbox`,`chef`

As the title mentions, it's about symlink mainly, other tags are just assocation with the context of the question.

If you see the view of the question, the question appears as if this is a virtualbox question.

[image]

I am not sure of the algorithm it uses to pick a tag to show in the page, but I think there should be a way to pick primary tag, it could be as simple as respecting the order by which it was added in the question.

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure of the algorithm it uses to pick a tag to show in the page

It uses the most popular tag (meaning that tag that is used most often in the site).

A simple way to ensure what is used in the title - use only the most relevant tags, remove "meta" tags that are not particularly helpful.

> I think there should be a way to pick primary tag

I believe that would be complicated - both in the UI and in ensuring it is used (what happens if tags are edited and the "primary tag" is removed?).

Comment: I think the person editing the question should be responsible for the effects it has.